# Ubuntu detects another monitor when I don't have any other monitor

Tags: 11.04, intel-graphics, monitor

Ubuntu detects a DVI monitor even if I don't have any. I only have a VGA monitor plugged. This is a problem because the game I play crashes when I have two monitors. But I only have one monitor plugged in. This only applies to Ubuntu 11.04, and Linux Distros with the latest Linux Kernel for some reason. The graphics card I'm using is  Intel's GMA 3150. It's the same graphics card used in some netbooks. But I have on a desktop. So, how can I make Ubuntu not detect it. I mean like get rid of it, not just turning off the monitor through the Monitor Preferences.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If it is only with the latest kernel, it may be a defect in the kernel, or drivers for the GPU may be a bit buggy with this kernel. Try rolling back to kernel and see if that does anything.

Good luck!